# How did the snifting valve in Newcomen's steam engine work?

Tags: engineering, steam-engines

Its function was to expel the air that came inside the cylinder along with the steam to prevent the engine to become "wind logged". Since the valve was non-return, how did Newcomen stopped steam from leaving after pushing out the air?

Comment: I think this should migrate to Engineering.SE since it's not an historical question.